# What is the point of storing biological samples in Trizol/TriSURE before RNA extraction?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, protocol

The [Wikipedia article on Trizol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trizol) says that it helps break the cells and maintain RNA integrity during homogenisation of samples. Does anybody know by how much Trizol improves RNA integrity compared to homogenisation without it? If somebody is extracting RNA from tissues without first storing them in Trizol, can you please tell me about the quality of your RNA?

Comment: These reagents denature RNases to protect RNA from degradation.